# I have accidentally pressed the "Do not show dialog again" button on wine and i cant seem to fix it. Is there a way to disable this function?

Tags: wine

I have pressed the "Do not show dialog again" checkmark and cant change it back to normal. I've pressed everything and nothing worked. Is this there a way to show the dialog again for the option for advanced/simple mode?

Comment: What is the dialog?

Comment: It gives me the option for simple mode / advanced mode but i accidentally pressed "Do not show dialog again"

Comment: Where do you find this dialog?

Comment: When i start a "Winows Excebutable" on wine.

Comment: What's the title of this dialog? You should have provided all the these details to start with.

Comment: "You are about to open a Wine file."

Answer (score 0):

This is a Wine message that warns you that Wine is about to execute the file as
a Windows executable.

As I don't use Wine, I don't know which setting controls this message.

I suggest to open up the
[Winecfg utility](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Using_Winecfg)
and search for this setting.
You could search for it also in the Wine configuration file `~/.wine/config`.

If nothing is found, the simplest solution to returning all settings to their
initial values, would be to uninstall Wine, remove `~/.wine/config`, and then
re-install Wine.